# How to dynamically update cells in a DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using [this](https://datatables.net/) datatables.

My code is like below

```
table = $('#invoices-table').DataTable({ ordering: false });
var currentPage = table.page();

rowNode = table.row.add([
    table_sr_no,
    '<a href="/view_debit_notes/' + data.id + '" class="view_debit_notes">' + data.debitnote_no + '</a>',
    '<td class="text-right">' + data.total + '</td>',
    'Serial No',
    '',
    '<a href="/seller/number">Active</a>',
    ''
]).draw();

var index = 0,
rowCount = table.data().length - 1,
insertedRow = table.row(rowCount).data(),
tempRow;

for (var i = rowCount; i > index; i--) {
    tempRow = table.row(i - 1).data();
    table.row(i).data(tempRow);
    table.row(i - 1).data(insertedRow);
}

table.page(currentPage).draw(false);
```

I am inserting a row at First position using below code in a previously generated table.

```
rowNode = table.row.add([
        table_sr_no,
        '<a href="/view_debit_notes/' + data.id + '" class="view_debit_notes">' + data.debitnote_no + '</a>',
        '<td class="text-right">' + data.total + '</td>',
        'Serial No',
        '',
        '<a href="/seller/number">Active</a>',
        ''
    ]).draw();
```

I think I have to do something in below code to re-generate the **New Serial Number**

```
for (var i = rowCount; i > index; i--) {
    tempRow = table.row(i - 1).data();
    table.row(i).data(tempRow);
    table.row(i - 1).data(insertedRow);
}
```

How can I dynamically generate Serial (**table_sr_no**) Number ?

I need **Serial Number** like below

[image]

Comment: What are the requirements for `table_sr_no`? What have you tried?

Comment: What is the meaning of `requirements for table_sr_no` ? Code mentioned in the question I tried.

Comment: Thanks @billynoah. I edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @ic3b3rg. I edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us three examples of valid serial numbers?

Comment: @ic3b3rg, Serial Numbers are Simple. like 1,2,3. I added an Image.

Comment: @billynoah, I added an image.

Comment: are you saying that you want the first cell to display the row number?

Comment: Yes, @billynoah.

Comment: thanks for explaining, I've retracted my close vote and offered a possible solution below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments my understanding is that you want the first column to act more or less like an auto-increment, where each cell contains a number referencing it's position in the table.  You can set the first cell in each row to it's parent row's index like this:

```
// select first cell in every row and iterate over them
$('#invoices-table tr td:first-child').each( function() {
    // get a reference to the datatable's cell and assign
    // the parent row's index as content
    table.cell(this).data($(this).parent().index()+1);
});
// redraw the table so new cell data will work with sorting and filtering
table.draw();
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm going to offer another solution here because I realized that the above will fail on tables with pagination / rows that aren't currently visible. Datatables offers it's own [`each()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/each()) method which can be called on nodes in a set.  To use it you can do something like this:

```
table.cells(':first-child').nodes().each(function(node, index) {
    table.cell(node).data(index + 1);
});
```

You'll note this is *very similar* to what I first suggested but it has the added benefit of accessing *all* the rows rather than just the visible rows.

Here's a snippet demonstrating:

```js
var dataSet = [
  ["", "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
  ["", "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"],
  ["", "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"],
  ["", "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060"],
  ["", "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
  ["", "Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000"],
  ["", "Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500"],
  ["", "Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900"],
  ["", "Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500"],
  ["", "Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600"],
  ["", "Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560"],
  ["", "Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000"],
  ["", "Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600"],
  ["", "Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500"],
  ["", "Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750"],
  ["", "Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500"],
  ["", "Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000"],
  ["", "Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2009/04/10", "$237,500"],
  ["", "Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2012/10/13", "$132,000"],
  ["", "Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500"],
  ["", "Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2011/09/03", "$345,000"],
  ["", "Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2009/06/25", "$675,000"],
  ["", "Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2011/12/12", "$106,450"],
  ["", "Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sidney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600"],
  ["", "Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
  ["", "Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
  ["", "Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
  ["", "Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
  ["", "Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
  ["", "Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
  ["", "Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sidney", "2769", "2011/06/02", "$95,400"],
  ["", "Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500"],
  ["", "Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000"],
  ["", "Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500"],
  ["", "Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
  ["", "Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [
      {title: "Row ID"},
      {title: "Name"},
      {title: "Position"},
      {title: "Office"},
      {title: "Extn."},
      {title: "Start date"},
      {title: "Salary"}
    ]
  });
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    table.cells(':first-child').nodes().each(function(node, index) {
      table.cell(node).data(index + 1);
    });
    // redraw table and keep current pagination
    table.draw(false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button>Click to reindex table</button><br><br>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: It is working like Magic. How can I be a JavaScript expert like you ?

Comment: @abuabu - I'm glad it worked for you.  Please see updated answer for even more details regarding tables with pagination.